# Subset a dataframe: identify combinations of columns that apear x times?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I know there are good tools for creative subsetting, but I'm not familiar with them, so your help is very much appreciated. I went trough similar questions and couldn't find an answer, but please point me to it if you think this is a duplicate.

Lets assume a `df` looking like this:

```
   Pop Loc BP
1    1   a 10
2    2   a 10
3    3   a 10
4    4   a 10
5    3   a 50
6    2   c 21
7    1   d 33
8    2   d  8
9    3   d  8
10   4   d  8
```

I want to identify which `Loc` are present in all 4 levels of `Pop` but considering `Loc` in combination with BP (i.e. in the above example row 5 and row 3 are different). The desired output should look like this:

```
   Pop Loc BP
1    1   a 10
2    2   a 10
3    3   a 10
4    4   a 10
```

In this example only the first 4 rows of `df` meet the condition, as `Loc=="a"` and `BP=="10"` exist in Pop 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Row 3 should be excluded because the combination `Loc=="a"` and `BP==50`, is only present in Pop 3, and rows 7-10 do not meet the conditions because `Loc=="d"` and `BP==8` are not present in Pop 1.

The solution has to bee something general and more or less effective, as in the real dataset length(levels) of `Loc`and `BP`is around 4,000 (`Pop` remains small).

I was thinking to use `paste()`to "merge" `Loc`and `BP` into a new column and then keep only the ones that appear the desired number of times (4 in this example). But I'm sure there is a better way.

Thanks

`dput()` to create `df`:

```
> df<-structure(list(Pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4), Loc = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "c", "d"
), class = "factor"), BP = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 50, 21, 33, 8, 8, 
8)), .Names = c("Pop", "Loc", "BP"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example using `plyr`, you can create a new id (using `interaction`) then process your comparisons by this id:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(transform(df,id =interaction(Loc,BP)),.(id),
      function(x)if(all(1:4%in%x$Pop))x)

  Pop Loc BP   id
1   1   a 10 a.10
2   2   a 10 a.10
3   3   a 10 a.10
4   4   a 10 a.10
```

Comment: Nice solution. Might want to change the inner function to test `if (all(1:4 %in% x$Pop))` since I think the OP just wants each value of `1:4` to exist in `Pop` in the subset data, and they might not necessarily come in that order.

Comment: @MasonDeCamillis good catch, thanks.My previous solution assumes that the data is ordered. I edit it know.

Comment: Thanks guys. Watch out that the first `df` data was wrong. I just corrected the dput.

Comment: Just to get my head over `ddply()` for something that is relevant for my real dataset. How would you write `function(x)` to do not restrict it to `all(1:4%in%x$Pop)` but to restrict it to say "at least in 3 different Pop no matter which they are"?

Comment: @A.Mstt this will not help you to master ddply. It is a basic logic. You can do something like `length(unique(x$Pop))>2`.

Answer (score 1):

A very general solution using base R, where you can specify the grouping columns, column where your required values are, and the actual required values:

```
 subsetCustom <- function(
  data,
  INDICES,
  requiredValueCol,
  requiredValues)
{
  subsetData <- by(
    data = data,
    INDICES = INDICES,
    FUN = function(subdata, requiredValueCol, 
                   requiredValues) {
      if (all(requiredValues %in% subdata[, requiredValueCol])) 
        out <- subdata
      else out <- NULL
      return(out)
    },
    requiredValueCol = requiredValueCol,
    requiredValues = requiredValues)

  subsetData <- do.call(rbind, subsetData)
  return(subsetData)    
}

subsetCustom(
  data = df, 
  INDICES = list(df$Loc, df$BP),
  requiredValueCol = "Pop",
  requiredValues = 1:4)
```